# Is it fine to use Core Data's NSManagedObjects instead of Normal Objects?

Tags: ios, core-data

If My app has a Model class called Note.

At the moment I have to Just create a Text Note and call an API and send it to the server.

But there are chances that later on, I will have to bring GMail style, draft facility for this Note.

So is it fine that I make it a Core Data entity upfront ?

I will pass nil for context for now, and when I will implement this feature I will pass the context of my application while creating it.

Also it feels nice to be able to control all the Models, whether being persisted or not,
from the same interface.

So that I can use the Core Data's Graphical interface to add and remove properties as required and aut-generate files unlike a hand-written NSObject models.

Can this have a performance hit or any other con ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mostly, this is fine and when their is no context involved I don't see a problem

BUT

you have to take care with threading Once you pass a context. the contexts and the MOMs that belong to them belong to a certain thread and cannot freely be passed around between threads!

Comment: So. I was thinnking to keep only one managedObjectCOntext in the app.
The ones that should be saved will be created with that context and others with just nil.

What you mean is that If I create an object with a context A in a thread and try to save it in contextB in a separated thread.

That can create a problem. right ?
So.. Cna it happen in my case ?

Also.. just in-case .. what all comes under 'you have to take care with threading '

in case this scenario happens ?

Comment: ruffly: everything you do with NSThread, dispatch_sync/async and NSOperationQueue

Comment: you must not interact with MOMs / the MOC on different threads

Comment: So.. if an app has one context for data. but it is also downloading some data and saving it in core data asynchronously in a separated thread.
This will create a problem ?
What would be the approach in such case ?